# Upgrading Classic app to Lightning Issue

Tags: lightning-experience, app

We are all aware of the feature of upgrading our classic apps to lightning version so that we can achieve the benefits of lightning apps.

But I am not able to see **Upgrade** option for one of my app named **Content**.
It is a standard app and it is available in lightning also. But I am not having an option to upgrade this app to lightning version so that I can keep two versions of this app each for Classic and Lightning.

Any help is much appreciated.

See the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Probably you are missing the screenshot.

Comment: I have added the screenshot

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? (Facing the same issue)

Answer (score 1):

As per Salesforce docs:

> Salesforce CRM Content is only available in Salesforce Classic

So due to this you can't upgrade this app to Lightning.

[Set Up Salesforce CRM Content](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_initialsetup.htm&type=5)

Comment: It is available in lightning also. I just want to keep two versions.